# Error when attempting to call SignInWithRedirect for Google sign-in. React Native, Expo, Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, expo, google-authentication

I have reinstalled firebase, expo, and refactored to be using V9 with no real progress. My signInWithEmailAndPassword works fine but I receive the same error with both popUp and Redirect.

```
TypeError: (0, \_auth.signInWithRedirect) is not a function. (In '(0, \_auth.signInWithRedirect)(auth, provider)', '(0, \_auth.signInWithRedirect)' is undefined)
```

I believe that it must not be importing correctly but I do not see how. I have authorized google auth in the firebase console and as stated tested the standard sign in and create user functions and they both have no error. My config and initialization both work for standard auth as well as firestore connections.

Import statements :

```
import {  
 getAuth,  
 onAuthStateChanged,  
 signInWithEmailAndPassword,  
 createUserWithEmailAndPassword,  
 signInWithRedirect,  
 GoogleAuthProvider,  
} from "firebase/auth";
```

Handle Google sign in function :

```
const auth = getAuth();

const signInWithGoogle = () => {  

 const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();  
 signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)  
.then((*result*) => {  
 *// This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.*  
 const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(*result*);  
 const token = credential.accessToken;  
 *// The signed-in user info.*  
 const user = *result*.user;  
 *// ...*  
})  
.catch((*error*) => {  
 *// Handle Errors here.*  
 const errorCode = *error*.code;  
 const errorMessage = *error*.message;  
 *// The email of the user's account used.*  
 const email = *error*.email;  
 *// The AuthCredential type that was used.*  
 const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(*error*);  
 *// ...*  
});  
  };
```

Any guidance on what I am missing is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any luck with this? I am currently experiencing the same exact issue.

Comment: Nothing that I have found. I think an external library may be required. If anyone has information regarding that please let me know.